# Tcplistener does not contain a constructor that takes an argument

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I just started using sockets but I seem unable to go any further because of some error. 
When I try to construct a TcpListener like this...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int port = 8888;

    Console.WriteLine("Starting TCP listener...");

    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(port);
}
```

..."TcpCLient" becomes red and tells me "Tcplistener does not contain a constructor that takes an argument"

I'm really frustrated because I didn't find anything on google/here and have no idea how to solve it.

I use .NET 4.5.2 with VS2015

I'll provide any further Information if necessary.

I'm looking forward to any solutions etc. and hope to start with sockets soon :D

Comment: The `TcpListener(int)` was depreciated, you should be using [`TcpListener(IPAddress, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Already tried this, same error just with 2 arguments instead. I kinda used the code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx as reference but still does;t seem to work...

Comment: Please give us the entire error text, it is missing part "takes an argument of type ... "

Comment: It is the whole error doens't say anything more than this...

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried the fully qualified name? `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener`?

Comment: Thanks :D If I write it like this: System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener listener = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(localAdress, port); it seems to work. Although it looks a little bit unclean^^

Comment: You should be able to add a `using System.Net.Sockets` at the top of the file and then go back to the shortened name.